# DOMException: Permission denied to access property "apply" on cross-origin object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

For the past day i've been working on FreeCodeCamp assignment "quote machine". Everything else is working except the tweet button. You can use the tweet any amount you want on one single quote, but not on multiple (meaning after youve tweeted one, you cannot go to next quote and tweet that).

The error i'm getting when trying to open new window is

> DOMException: Permission denied to access property "apply" on cross-origin object

I've been googling that error for a while but I cannot find a fix that I could apply

[Here's the project](https://codepen.io/breeku/pen/aGKwqQ) (it's quite small)

snip

```js
// snip
methods:{
  twitter() {
    this.twitter = window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?text='+this.quote+'&hashtags=quotes');
  },
  refreshQuote() {
    // etc
```

```html
<a @click="refreshQuote">
///
</a>
<v-btn fab depressed outline large class="center" @click="twitter">
```

The reason im calling for `tweet()` is because i couldn't get `window.open`work at the `@click`, got error

> Error in event handler for "click": "TypeError: window is undefined"

Thanks.

Comment: _"...or something along those lines"_ <- it's much better if you can be as specific as possible

Comment: Error in event handler for "click": "TypeError: window is undefined". I'll add that to main post then.

Comment: Looks like your HTML / template is malformed. Your `<transition>` tag starts inside the `<a>` tag but `</transition>` is outside `</a>`. _Update: this does not appear to be the source of your problem though_

Comment: You also have some `<h1>` and `<span>` tags malformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a `window` handle (the return value of [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)) to `this.twitter` which up until that point is your `twitter` method.

I see no reason to keep a reference to the opened window so just change your code to

```
twitter() {
  window.open(`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?text=${encodeURIComponent(this.quote)}&hashtags=quotes`)
}
```

---

Also as mentioned above, your HTML is malformed with several closing tags out of order. You should fix that.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RyJBXa

Comment: You're right, thanks a ton for your time! I tried bunch of things but somehow didnt try that. I'm still wondering why @click="window.open" doesn't work :| But that's a question on its own.

Comment: @breke I'd have to dig into the Vue source code but I suspect template expressions are evaluated against the component / Vue context, ie it would become `this.window.open(...)`